# simple array programme to calculate square roots of numbers

Tags: arrays

okay so this is the task 'Write a program which stores an array of 100 integers holding squares - 1,4,9,16... etc.  The program should ask the user to input a square to search for, E.g. 144, which should then search the array for 144 and display "144 is the square of 12".  If the number is not a square it should search the array for the number and display "That number is not a square".  The program should just keep asking for input until the user enters 9999 whereby the program ends'

I have most of it working it's just the part where you need to display "that number is not a square" because I am not sure where to put it, I tried putting it in the loop but then it jut displayed it 100 times haha. I have a feeling I should use a Boolean true or false but I really don't know how to do that.

The code i have so far for the part i'm stuck is

```
public void search()
    {
        int number= 0;
        int root = 0;
        boolean  found= true ;



    do{
        System.out.println("enter a square number to search for");
        number= Genio.getInteger();

        for (int i = 1 ;i<101; i++)
        {

            if(number==square[i])
            {
                root = (int)(java.lang.Math.sqrt(number));  
                System.out.println("The square root of " + number + " is " + root);

            }

        }
    }  while (number!=9999);
```

### }

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. p.s if you need anymore of the code to understand more just ask :)

EDIT
I have tried doing the way it was suggested but that still didn't work and now I have tried doing this

```
   public void search()
    {
        int number= 0;
        int root = 0;
        boolean found;



    do{
        System.out.println("enter a square number to search for");
        number= Genio.getInteger();
        found = false;
        for (int i = 1 ;i<101; i++)
        {

            if(number==square[i])
            {
                root = (int)(java.lang.Math.sqrt(number));  
                found = true;
                System.out.println("The square root of " + number + " is " + root);


            }
           if(number!=square[i])
           {
               found= false;
               break;
            }

        }
        if(found=false){

                System.out.println("not a square");
        }
    }  while (number!=9999);
}
```

but it only works for the first time then it doesn't work again, here is the output I got for example.

```
enter a square number to search for
5
not a root
enter a square number to search for
9
The square root of 9 is 3
enter a square number to search for
5
enter a square number to search for
5
enter a square number to search for
```

Comment: just put the message after the for 1-100 loop... with a conditional to print it only if the loop did NOT find a square  you already have declared a Boolean flag named found... set it to true inside the if statement, and use it to control printing the " is not a square" message

Comment: I changed it to Boolean = false;

Comment: I changed it to Boolean = false; and added an  if(found== false)
            {System.out.println("not a root");
            }     but it still doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void search()
{
    int number= 0;
    int root = 0;
    boolean found;



do{
    System.out.println("enter a square number to search for");
    number= Genio.getInteger();
    found = false;
    for (int i = 1 ;i<101; i++)
    {

        if(number==square[i])
        {
            root = (int)(java.lang.Math.sqrt(number));  
            found = true;
            System.out.println("The square root of " + number + 
                                       " is " + root);
            break;
        }

    }
    if(!found){
       //Print your error message...
    }

}  while (number!=9999);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help anyway I really did appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    public void search()
        {
            int number= 0;
            int root = 0;
            boolean found;



        do{
            System.out.println("enter a square number to search for");
            number= Genio.getInteger();
            found = false;
            for (int i = 1 ;i<101; i++)
            {

                if(number==square[i])
                {
                    root = (int)(java.lang.Math.sqrt(number));  
                    found = true;
                    System.out.println("The square root of " + number + " is " + root);
                    break;

                }

            }
            if(!found){
                    //Print your error message...
            }
        }  while (number!=9999);
}
```